# How to move jQuery handler (or how do you call that?) from one object to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handler, jquery-events

I made the jsfiddle working example. Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/SsqEv/

Basically I create a simple html markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="test1">click me</div>
</div>
```

And the following Javascript code:

```
// attach click event
$('#test1').click(function() {alert('test');});
// create a new strring that will be appended to the container
var data = '<div id="test2">click me 2</div>';
// move click handler from #test1 to #test2
data = $(data).bind("click", {}, $("#test1").data("events").click[0]);
// add element to the DOM
$("#container").append(data);
// remove click from #test1
$('#test1').unbind("click");
```

This all works. Now, let's assume I have a custom script with some jQuery contextMenu plugin and I attach the context menu to `ul li` elements:

```
$("ul#vertical-menu li a[data-menuitemid]").contextMenu({
    menu: 'myMenu',
    beforeShow: function(contextMenu, item) {
        if ($(item).parent('li').hasClass('state-ok')) {
            $(contextMenu).children('.ready').hide();
        } else {
            $(contextMenu).children('.noready').hide();
        }
    }
}, function(action, el, pos) {
    changeStatus(model.id, action, $(el).attr('data-menuitemid'), el);
});
```

Sometimes I need to remove li and when this is done, I need to attach the contextMenu in the same way. The best option would be to move the contextMenu from the removed `li` to the added one. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**
I am using this contextMenu: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/

I would like to bind it 'live' to all `ul li` elements, because I have difficulties attaching contextMenu to new dynamically added `li`s. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Esailija: I saw you fixed the formatting. Is there a shortcut for automatic indentation? Or did you do that manually?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/petkaantonov/chromebeautify

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are doing here. Why are you "moving an event handler"? It seems to be a very strange thing to do. It would seem be easier to keep a reference to the handler and just assign that to the new element. Or use a delegated event handler instead. And the context menu isn't an event handler, so that "event handler moving" thing doesn't apply here. It probably depends on content menu plugin you are using. I think you conceptually completely on the wrong path here, but without a bigger picture it's difficult to say.

Comment: I don't think that plugin supports what you want to do. Have you considered binding it to the parent element instead of the separate items?=

Comment: RoToRa: I have considered it and it's not an option. Too much of a hassle when some of the li items do not have a context menu attached to them...

Comment: I u want to bind live event to all li of ul tag then u can use on function `$('ul').on('click','li',function(){ ...});`. here i modified ur [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsqEv/1/)